# Как поднять стабильность работы с чужим сайтом во время распродаж

Tags: браузер

Кинули мне тут ссылочку на сайт, где предлагается купить смартфон по акции - за тысячу рублей вместо 14ти.

И вот я думаю, как бы честным способом (без написания скриптов/ботов) попробовать выиграть.

У меня простой вопрос: могу ли я как-то затвикать браузер (ну, допустим, мой любимый Firefox или широкораспространённый хром), чтобы он как-то более устойчиво работал с сайтом под большой нагрузкой?

Вообще, как ведёт себя в общем случае сайт под нагрузкой? Долго устанавливается соединение с веб-сервером (до момента получения первого байта), медленная скорость скачивания картинки/капчи/самой страницы, постоянно рвётся соединение?

Comment: Понять бы, причём тут смартфон со своей акцией, чесный метод - без ботов и "затвиканный браузер" )))

Comment: А там точно нужно использовать браузер? Нельзя обойтись запросами из скрипта?

Comment: @Darth Cкрипты запрещены - могут (если найдут) аннулировать участие. И лучше не полагаться на авось (вряд ли сможешь апеллировать к тому, что "вам показалось"), а попробовать поискать альтернативные пути без скриптов, качающих капчу и жмущих на кпопки.

Comment: Посмотри на Selenium

Comment: Под нагрузкой сайт начинает тупить по времени отклика, сбрасывать соединения периодически, пока не затыкается совсем. Я издевался над своим с помощью loader.io https://kagg.eu/10000-clients-second-wordpress/